# selenium python javascript click button

Tags: python

I am having problems with my selenium script.
I want to webscrape a website that is running on javascript.
I have been gathering a lot of information on the internet but i can't find the solution.
[picture of the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgvcj.png)
[picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNOVB.png)
In this post i have also submitted a printscreen of the HTML code.
Basically: i want click on the accept button when i load the website but i can't figure how to do this.

searching on different websites for the solution.

Can you guys help me with my script, i have been trying and testing a lot but i can't figure it out.
thank you.

code:

```py
from config import keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


def order(k):

    chrome_path = 
    r"C:\Users\ltewo\PycharmProjects\livebetting\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get(keys['url'])
    xpath_button_accept = "//div[@class='cookieButtons']//a[@class='button 
    accept']"
    button_accept = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_button_accept)
    xpath_button_accept.click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    order(keys)
```

Comment: Please paste your code, instead of the picture.

Comment: @bhansa, i have paste the code.

Comment: @bhansa thank you for your answer, but i tried to run the code with the following line: time.sleep(15). I still got a error that python could not locate the element.

Comment: please try the code in my answer and also check the link which I have put in answer.

Comment: @bhansa i have paste the code again (updated). Now i get the timeout error so that means that python cannot locate the given xpath right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for that element to load on the page, so use:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'XpathOfMyElement')))
```

I noticed that the cookie panel was inside an **iframe** and was not directly accessible, I have updated the below, please check it's working now.

Updated your code:

```py
from config import keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


def order(keys):

    chrome_path = r"C:\Users\ltewo\PycharmProjects\livebetting\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get(keys['url'])
    driver.switch_to.frame('r42CookieBar')
    button_accept = driver.find_element_by_class_name('accept')
    button_accept.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     order(keys)
```

Comment: it seems like selenium cant locate the button because it's rendered with Java script. Maybe I need to use different technique. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the url? so that I can try running it once.

Comment: Just fyi that I tried the code on some other website which had same kind of cookie banner and it works.

Comment: this is the url: https://www.ns.nl/. Can you tell me on which website u tried the code?

Comment: I tried it [here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/the-selenium-click-command)

Comment: I will compare the websites with each other. Did you got it working on https://www.ns.nl ?

Comment: I have updated the code, you need to switch the frame since the cookie panel is in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#update
driver.implicity_wait(10)


xpath_button_accept = "//div[@class='cookieButtons']//a[@class='button accept']"

button_accept = your_browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_button_accept)
button_accept.click()
```

Comment: @Wonka- thank you for your answer. i still get a error with 'unable to locate element'. I have inserted a print screen of my code.

Comment: @Lobbel can you post the url or complete html?

Comment: @Lobbel you miss a line in your post, the line to get the element. (at the img its ok). Check my edit, the implicity_wait

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried this line before: time.sleep(15), just to test the code but it still gives a error. It cannot locate the element.

Comment: @Lobbel I hope the sleep line was after .get(url) right? can you post the url? I wanna check where element is.

Comment: i have posted the updated version, i now get a time-out error so that means that python cannot locate the xpath right ?